# How do I install django-ckeditor?

Tags: django, ckeditor

In Stack Overflow there's two questions about [this editor](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ckeditor/), and nobody answers!!!

So I'm asking how to install this Django package to my project??
I've followed [these steps](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ckeditor/#installation) already, have no errors, nothing, and still the form stays the same. Why??

Edit: heres model

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.db                import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _, ugettext
from ckeditor.fields          import RichTextField

class Newsletter(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(
        _(u'Title'),
        max_length=200,
        help_text=_(u'Newsletter title'),
        )

    body = RichTextField()

    date = models.DateField(
         _(u'Date'),
         help_text=_(u'Set date when this newsletter should be send') 
    )    

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title',]
```

forms.py

```
from models import Newsletter, Mail
class NewsletterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Newsletter
```

view:

```
from newsletter.models import Newsletter, Mail
from newsletter.forms  import NewsletterForm, MailForm

def newsletters_add(request):
    form = NewsletterForm()
    tpl  = "form_newsletter.html"

    return render_to_response(tpl, RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form,
    }))
```

All form outputed succesfully with {{ form }} tag

settings.py (of the project)

```
CKEDITOR_MEDIA_PREFIX  = "/media/ckeditor/"
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH   = "/www/vhosts/sender/media/newsletter/uploads/"
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PREFIX = "http://******/media/newsletter/uploads/"
CKEDITOR_RESTRICT_BY_USER = True

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Basic',
    },
}


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    #'tagging',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'ckeditor',
    'mailer',
    'newsletter'

)
```

Comment: Did you also use the field or the widget?

Comment: Can you paste the generated HTML around the form? I think it might have to do with media definitions, but I can't say for sure without seeing the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok sorry i was an idiot. in documentation there's no words about including JS manually somehow! so just include it

```
<script src="http://****/media/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Developers are blind in there or something?

Comment: see other answer - the right way to include js. However, I did that and I'm still having a problem with not having Django_CKEditor_config as a js global...

Comment: Can you share the media root, media url values for your project, I'm stuck with ckeditor from 2 days

Answer (score 6):

The media needed to display the widget correctly should be stored in the form's `media` object. You can output the tag for needed js in your template with `{{ form.media }}`. The admin should do this automatically, while in your custom views you have to do it yourself... See the django documentation on [form media](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/media/) for more information!

Comment: it would be nice to mention this in documentation of django-ckeditor.. for now {{ form.media }} outputs - nothing.