# django-ckeditor to Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-ckeditor

I've installed django-ckeditor on django 1.5 as instructed in the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ckeditor/#installation).
I've changed TextField in my applications models.py to RichTextField as said in the docs.
However I still see blank textarea in the Django admin instead of the ckeditor.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494912/how-do-i-install-django-ckeditor) was asked 3 years ago and none of the answers worked for me.
The ckeditor.js loads just fine when I get the page.
Any suggestions? 
my app name is newsfeed.

models.py:

```
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from cms.models import Page
from django.db import models
from time import time
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace('.','_'),filename)


# Create your models here.
class NewsFeed (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(('Feed Name'),max_length=200,help_text=('Feed name is visible only in edit mode'))
    publisher = models.CharField(('Publisher'),max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/newsfeed/get/%i" % self.id

class NewsItem(models.Model):
    feed_id = models.ForeignKey(NewsFeed)
    title = models.CharField(('Title'),max_length=200)
    subtitle = models.CharField(('Sub-Title'),max_length=350,help_text=('Subtitles are displayed in auto-scroller and has max characters of 350'))
    #body = models.TextField(('Content'),blank=True,help_text=('Content is NOT visible in auto-scroller !'))
    body = RichTextField()      
    url = models.URLField(("Link"), blank=True, null=True)
    page_link = models.ForeignKey(Page, verbose_name=("page"), blank=True, null=True, help_text=("A link to a page has priority over a text link."))
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Publish Date')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(('Published'), default=False)


class NewsFeedPlugin(CMSPlugin):
    newsfeed = models.ForeignKey(NewsFeed)
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from newsfeed.models import NewsFeed,NewsItem
from cms.admin.placeholderadmin import PlaceholderAdmin


class NewsItemInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = NewsItem
    extra=0

class NewsFeedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [NewsItemInline]
    class Media:
       js = ('ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')
admin.site.register(NewsFeed,NewsFeedAdmin)
```

config.js from ckeditor:

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2013, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.html or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this would be by making use of `class Media` of Django's `ModelAdmin`.

Suppose you have an `Article` model with a `TextField` to which you wish to add ckeditor. Assuming you have kept the `ckeditor.js` file inside your project's `static` folder, the following is what you should do:

**admin.py**

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    # your code here 
    ...

    class Media:
        js = ('ckeditor.js',)
        # do not write '/static/ckeditor.js' as Django automatically looks 
        # in the static folder
```

That's it.

If you wish to add configuration files for ckeditor or any more JavaScript files, just do this:

```
js = ('ckeditor.js', 'configuration-ckeditor.js')
```

In case you wish to add TinyMCE instead of ckeditor, I have a repository on GitHub to make it easier: https://github.com/xyres/django-tinymce-noapp

**Update**

After looking at your configuration file, I am certain the problem is not in Django but in your config file.

You need to tell CKEditor to which field to add the editor to. So, delete everything from your configuration file and add only this one line:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('textarea');
```

This would replace the textarea with an editor.

Don't forget to add this config file to the `class Media`.

Comment: Did not work for me, still get the regular textarea instead of ckeditor

Comment: @IliyaTamarkin May I take a look at your configuration file?

Comment: Now I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: textarea is not defined" in javascript when I load the page.

Comment: @IliyaTamarkin Oops. Sorry. Missed out the quotes! It should be `'textarea'` instead of `textarea`. Updated answer.

Comment: Now I get the following error in chrome:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined 
(anonymous function)CKEDITOR.replace 
ckeditor.js:314a
 ckeditor.js:314
ckeditor.js:318 config.js:12

Comment: The CKeditor shows in the html code as I can see ckeditor datatype in the textarea but visually there is just a blank text box

Answer (score 0):

you may follow this step of github-django ckeditor and it will run succesfully with ckeditor as output. I have verified by making the models and testing it:
link:https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor